The last letter of my name is missing on my bank account information, should I keep trying to fix it?
I live in Mexico and I've got my first debit card. I have three names. In total (counting spaces) I need 21 characters to write them. After realizing that the last letter of my last name is missing in my personal bank information and on the automatic emails I receive from the bank, I went to the bank to try to fix it. I was told that there's a character limit for writing names, and since my name was too long, it was cropped. Other important information (like my address and the Mexican equivalent of the SSN) are spelled correctly.
They asked me not to worry and let it pass, but I don't feel comfortable with my name being wrong. I just linked my account information to PayPal (where I had no problems writing my full name), and I'm worried that this disparity will give rise to problems in the future.
Is it normal to have the personal information cropped? I'm not sure whether the limit on characters is a real thing, but every time I go to ask for a change I get the same answer.
Edit: Just to clarify, I have three first names (say Jane1, Jane2, Jane3) and two family names (Doe1, Doe2). My problem was with the last first name being cropped.


Is it normal to have the personal information cropped? I'm not sure whether the limit on characters is a real thing, but every time I go to ask for a change I get the same answer.

It is and it is. In the older systems in the banking world (those based on the good old IBM Mainframe systems) there was definitely a limited pre-allocated space for names, which was shorter than names are in many cultures (not just Mexican, long names exist in some European countries, India, Middle East). So the names are cropped or abbreviated.
On credit/debit cards the name is embossed/printed on the card, where the space is physically restricted, and is also encoded in the magnetic stripe and the chip, where the space is also limited, so there you have space constraints as well.
You can consider abbreviating middle names, if it is possible, otherwise... You're stuck with the limitations of the system. If the name is not misspelled, just the last character is missing, then you can provide the same explanation if anyone asks.

That said, 21 characters is not a lot. For payment cards, the name field is up to 26 characters, including spaces (see ISO/IEC 7813). But if there are separate fields for first and last names in the bank's system, it may be split 10/16 for example, or something similar.

Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed, the fields for first and last name were separate.

"you can provide the same explanation if anyone asks" -- but what about, e.g., online transactions that might simply fail due to mismatch with no opportunity for OP to explain? I think this is part of OP's concern that "this disparity will give rise to problems in the future".

@nanoman Payment processors should be well aware of the limitations of the banking limitations... most notably because the mainstream payment processors still use the very mainframes and old languages in which such limitations arise. (I am not sure if knowing that Visa still uses IBM mainframes and COBOL will be a bright or dark spot in your day, but that's how it is...)

@MatthieuM. It's not to do with the language or the computer, but the fact that the formats transitioned from punch cards, which have limited information storage, and that fixed-length data formats are very efficient to parse, important when your system handles tens of thousands of transactions per second.

+1 to @user71659. Even in the modern world there are physical limitations - physical card size, check size, envelop window for addresses, printed statements need to fit the design, etc etc.

@nanoman beyond what Matthieu M. says, the verification that the payment processors do actually goes back to the issuing bank to make the decision. With any sort of luck, they understand their own limitations.

@user71659: Some languages do make it easier to have fixed-length fields (C, for example), and legacy matters of course. 10 Ks/s won't be much of a limitation, a single core could communicate in JSON at that rate, with off-the-shelves JSON parsers.

As a software developer, I want to point out that the unspecified length of text used to be a massive issue back when hardware specs were tight and memory availability would be allocated to the character (before you've input your text, hence why the max length is set before you know what text you want to enter). This really only stopped being an issue in the last 15-20 years, and it takes considerably longer than that for established systems to stop working in a way that they've already been built to work.

@nanoman "online transactions that might simply fail due to mismatch" I've been entering NAME CARDHOLDER everywhere from Stripe to Amazon for over 10 years and it was never rejected because of name mismatch. The few times something didn't work, I found out why, fixed it and still completed the payment as NAME CARDHOLDER. Two things though: I'm in Europe and I use debit cards.

This is a partial answer, addressing some practical concerns you may have. I work for a payment processing company in Europe, but I believe online payments standards are very similar throughout the Western world.
I would generally just follow directions like "please input your name as it appears on your card" literally - write exactly what is printed.
Modern online payment systems use a probability-based system for identifying the cardholder. It would be unlikely that an automated system would reject a payment because of one missing character in a middle name (so unlikely that I'd consider such a system misconfigured). Typically you can completely omit the middle names without issue, or abbreviate your first name (e.g. Alexander to Alex).
It is possible that the transaction would be flagged for some sort of extra review, but this would normally be invisible to you unless it lead to your bank automatically requesting confirmation of the transaction. Large or unusual transactions are more likely to be investigated. This wouldn't have any impact on you beyond the call/message/app notification you get asking you to confirm the transaction.

As anecdotal evidence to support this, even if my card includes my middle name, I have never had an issue when I leave it off the billing information.   I haven't actually tried to use a different middle name though.

@MichaelRichardson I think a different middle name would usually result in a rejected transaction, but you can get away with extra middle names.

I was also considering to write my name cropped on PayPal, but since PayPal can ask for pictures of an ID with my full name to verify my identity I didn't want to run the risk. It's good to know that the probability of my transactions being flagged as shady is low if only a letter is missing. Thank you very much for your answer.

@Amelian I didn't want to run the risk – what risk? It does seem like you're worried about this, but it's not like you'd get investigated for fraud or something. If the transaction fails, you try again. If you somehow get blocked, contact the support and get it resolved. If you're not up to something shady, you will be fine.

@WhatHiFi thank you, I was just worried because I'm planning to open a little online business for a second income, and I've read a few stories of people getting permanently banned from PP for (allegedly) no clear reason at all, so I wanted to start clean and avoid any inconsistency. But so far my missing letter is not causing any trouble.

@Amelian alright, then you do have a point and it may make a difference. Who knows, what if the fact that it shows up differently on an invoice may affect your business accounting. In personal life to me it never mattered whether invoice says paid by John Doe. Business is different. I take my argument back then.

@WhatHiFi I didn't want to update the question to avoid it getting more attention, but I got a new debit card with another bank, they have 40 characters available for the name so I had no issue writing mine. I linked the good bank account to my new business PP account now. Thank you anyway for your input!
